# Creating a [materialised]view from generic data in Oracle/Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle, view, pivot

I have a generic datamodel with 3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE Properties 
(
  propertyId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(80) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
  customerId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customerName varchar(80) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE PropertyValues
(
  propertyId int(11) NOT NULL,
  customerId int(11) NOT NULL,
  value varchar(80) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO Properties VALUES (1, 'Age');
INSERT INTO Properties VALUES (2, 'Weight');
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (1, 'Bob');
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (2, 'Tom');
INSERT INTO PropertyValues VALUES (1, 1, '34');
INSERT INTO PropertyValues VALUES (2, 1, '80KG');
INSERT INTO PropertyValues VALUES (1, 2, '24');
INSERT INTO PropertyValues VALUES (2, 2, '53KG');
```

What I would like to do is create a view that has as columns all the ROWS in Properties and has as rows the entries in Customers. The column values are populated from PropertyValues.
e.g.

```
 customerId Age   Weight
 1          34    80KG
 2          24    53KG
```

I'm thinking I need a stored procedure to do this and perhaps a materialised view (the entries in the table "Properties" change rarely).
Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy enough to generate a view with dynamic SQL:

```
create or replace procedure gen_view
as
    cols_stmt varchar2(32767);
    from_stmt varchar2(32767);
    subq_name varchar2(30);
begin
    for r in ( select * from properties
               order by propertyid )
    loop
        subq_name := 'pv_'||trim(to_char(r.propertyid)); 
        cols_stmt := cols_stmt || ', '|| subq_name ||'.value as '||r.name;
        from_stmt := from_stmt || ' left join ( select value, customerid from propertyvalues where propertyid = '
            ||trim(to_char(r.propertyid))||') '||subq_name
            ||' on '||subq_name||'.customerid = customers.customerid';
    end loop;
    execute immediate 'create or replace view eav_view as select customers.customerid, customers.customername'
                        || cols_stmt
                        || ' from customers '
                        || from_stmt;
end gen_view;
/
```

Here's it working:

```
SQL> exec gen_view

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from eav_view
  2  /

CUSTOMERID
----------
CUSTOMERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WEIGHT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1
Bob
34
80KG

         2
Tom
24
53KG


SQL>
```

Let's create a new property and insert values for it for some of the customers...

```
SQL> insert into properties values (3, 'FavouriteIceCream')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into propertyvalues values (3, 1, 'Cherry Garcia')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> exec gen_view

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from eav_view
  2  /

CUSTOMERID
----------
CUSTOMERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WEIGHT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FAVOURITEICECREAM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1
Bob
34
80KG
Cherry Garcia

         2
Tom
24
53KG

SQL>
```

> "I'm thinking I need a stored
>   procedure to do this and perhaps a
>   materialised view (the entries in the
>   table "Properties" change rarely)."

The problem is, Properties *are* going to change, and I'm guessing you will have no oversight of when that happens.  So you are going to find it very hard to apply the changes to a materialized view.  This matters because changing the projection of a materialized view necessitates dropping it.  So it's quite difficult to do this without an interruption to service.  A similar consideration applies to the regular view , but the outage is almost zero.

If you do want to convert the view statement into a materialized view note that Oracle doesn't seem to like the ANSI-92 syntax when it comes to materialized views (it hurls ORA-12054).  I'm not sure why that should be, but the problem went away when I changed to the older joining technique, which is annoying because the outer join syntax is clunkier.

A solution without the need to re-create database objects would be to use the dynamic SQL in a function which returns a Ref Cursor, which maps to a JDBC ResultSet:

```
create or replace function get_eav_view
    return sys_refcursor
as
    cols_stmt varchar2(32767);
    from_stmt varchar2(32767);
    subq_name varchar2(30);
    return_value sys_refcursor;
begin
    for r in ( select * from properties
               order by propertyid )
    loop
        subq_name := 'pv_'||trim(to_char(r.propertyid)); 
        cols_stmt := cols_stmt || ','|| subq_name ||'.value as '||r.name;
        from_stmt := from_stmt || ' left join ( select value, customerid from propertyvalues where propertyid = '
            ||trim(to_char(r.propertyid))||') '||subq_name
            ||' on '||subq_name||'.customerid = customers.customerid';
    end loop;
    open return_value for
            'select customers.customerid, customers.customername'
                    || cols_stmt
                    || ' from customers '
                    || from_stmt;
    return return_value;
end get_eav_view;
/
```

This will always return the latest projection:

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec :rc := get_eav_view

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

CUSTOMERID
----------
CUSTOMERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WEIGHT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FAVOURITEICECREAM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1
Bob
34
80KG
Cherry Garcia

         2
Tom
24
53KG


SQL>
```

Now, if we add a new property it gets picked up immediately:

```
SQL>  insert into properties values (4, 'StarSign')
   2  /

1 row created.

SQL>  insert into propertyvalues values (4, 2, 'Aries')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> exec :rc := get_eav_view

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

CUSTOMERID
----------
CUSTOMERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WEIGHT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FAVOURITEICECREAM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STARSIGN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1
Bob
34
80KG
Cherry Garcia


         2
Tom
24
53KG

Aries


SQL>
```

Comment: Fantastic! And a great example. Mmm. CherryGarcia.